# How Grafana resolution works when showing more points than Prometheus have

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I scrape metrics with Prometheus every 30 seconds. When I check in Prometheus graph:

`elasticsearch_jvm_memory_max_bytes{}[2m]`

I can see there is range vector with 4 values:

```
2095185920 @1626523484.001
2095185920 @1626523514.001
2095185920 @1626523544.001
2095185920 @1626523574.001
```

That makes sense, **30s * 4 values = 2m**. When I run the same command in Grafana, I can see data points every **15s**:
[image]

In the example above, there is 3 data points in **14:43:30**, **14:43:45** and **14:44:00**. I can see this with query resolution **1/1**. If I set resolution to **1/2**, graph looks normal, with data points every **30s**. I read about resolution in grafana and maybe I did not understat correctly, but I would expect that 1/1 should be one point in panel per 1 data point from prometheus. 1/2 should show 1 point in panel per 2 data points from prometheus, etc...
Could anybody explain me, what am I missing or why grafana works like this (with some example)?

Grafana: **v7.3.6**

Thank you.

Comment: To understand your question I tried jvm_memory_max_bytes{} which is working but jvm_memory_max_bytes{}[2m] gives me an error: "invalid expression type \"range vector\" for range query, must be Scalar or instant Vector".

Answer (score 2):

Grafana sends request to [/api/v1/query_range](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#range-queries) endpoint at Prometheus when it needs points for building the graph. Grafana sends the following args to the endpoint:

- `query` - the PromQL query to execute
- `start` and `end` - the time range for the graph
- `step` - the interval between points on the graph

This endpoint always returns points with timestamps `start`, `start+step`, `start+2*step`, ..., `start+N*step`, where `start+N*step` <= `end`. Prometheus executes the provided `query` independently per each such timestamp. Obviously, the real samples stored in Prometheus can be missing at the requested timestamps. That's why Prometheus returns sample values with the closest timestamps. See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#staleness) for details.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense, but what is a good work around? I just want 1/1 resolution in my grafana graphs.

Comment: Unfortunately Grafana datasource for Prometheus cannot query and display raw samples stored in Prometheus. You can query raw samples and process them on your side if this is needed - https://valyala.medium.com/analyzing-prometheus-data-with-external-tools-5f3e5e147639 .

Comment: Turns out I was using $__interval when I should have been using $__rate_interval for a rate query